# Split Stored Procedure With Left Outer Joins To Separate SP For Performance

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, join, outer-join

I have a situation where I have a stored procedure that does a lot of  `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s because I am retrieving two types of games, pools and brackets. They diverge off a main entity called game.

As of now I am grabbing all pool and bracket games in one stored procedure. Because pool games won't have bracket data I need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the pool query of the SQL and vice-versa for the bracket games.

I was thinking I could split these up into separate stored procedures and get rid of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Is this something that would speed up performance?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Test].[Test]
    @Page INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @SortOrder NVARCHAR(100) = 'Id',
    @SortDirection VARCHAR(4) = 'ASC',
    @EventId INT = NULL,
    @DivisionId INT = NULL,
    @DivisionTeamId INT = NULL,
    @Date DATETIME = NULL,
    @SearchToken NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @MemberId INT = NULL,
    @Gametype INT = NULL,
    @GymCourtId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    WITH PagedResults AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE  
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Date' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Date DESC, game.Time DESC, addr.Location DESC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Date' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Date ASC, game.Time ASC, addr.Location ASC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Time' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Time DESC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Time' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Time ASC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Gym' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY addr.Location DESC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Gym' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY addr.Location ASC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Court' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY court.Name DESC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Court' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY court.Name ASC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Type' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN DivisionTeamPoolGame.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 WHEN divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE NULL END DESC, divisionBracket.Name ASC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Type' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN DivisionTeamPoolGame.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 WHEN divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE NULL END ASC, divisionBracket.Name DESC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Division' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(poolDivision.Name, bracketDivision.Name) DESC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Division' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(poolDivision.Name, bracketDivision.Name) ASC, game.Id ASC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.TeamName DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.TeamName ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.TeamName DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.TeamName ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayScore' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.TeamName DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayScore' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.TeamName ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeScore' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.TeamName DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeScore' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.TeamName ASC, game.Id DESC)              
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.Score DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.Score ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.Score DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.Score ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Id DESC)
                ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Id ASC)
            END  AS [Row],
            CASE  
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Date' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Date ASC, game.Time ASC, addr.Location ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Date' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Date DESC, game.Time DESC, addr.Location DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Time' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Time ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Time' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Time DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Gym' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY addr.Location ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Gym' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY addr.Location DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Court' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY court.Name ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Court' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY court.Name DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Type' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN DivisionTeamPoolGame.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 WHEN divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE NULL END ASC, divisionBracket.Name DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Type' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN DivisionTeamPoolGame.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 WHEN divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE NULL END DESC, divisionBracket.Name ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Division' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(poolDivision.Name, bracketDivision.Name) ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'Division' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(poolDivision.Name, bracketDivision.Name) DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.Score ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'AwayTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY awayTeam.Score DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.Score ASC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortOrder = 'HomeTeam' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY homeTeam.Score DESC, game.Id DESC)
                WHEN @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Id ASC)
                ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY game.Id DESC)
            END  AS [RowReverse],

            game.Id,
            divisionBracketParticipantPart.Number,
            divisionBracketParticipantPart.[Round],
            (CASE 
                WHEN DivisionTeamPoolGame.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                WHEN divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                ELSE NULL 
             END
            ) AS GameType,
            game.[Date], 
            game.[Time],
            game.TwitterId,
            game.FacebookId,
            gymCourt.Id AS GymCourtId,
            COALESCE(eventGymPool.[Order], eventGymBracket.[Order]) AS GymOrder,
            gymCourt.[Order] AS GymCourtOrder,
            addr.Location AS GymName,
            gym.Id AS GymId,
            gym.Abbr AS GymAbbr,
            court.Name AS CourtName,
            court.ShortHand AS CourtAbbr,
            court.[Order] AS CourtOrder,
            addr.StreetAddress,
            addr.ExtendedAddress,
            addr.City,
            stat.Name AS StateRegion,
            addr.PostalCode,
            addr.Longitude,
            addr.Latitude,
            awayTeam.Score AS AwayTeamScore,
            awayTeam.Forfeited AS AwayTeamForfeited,
            awayTeam.DivisionTeamId AS AwayDivisionTeamId,
            awayTeam.ActivatedDate AS AwayTeamActivationDate,
            awayTeam.TeamName AS AwayTeamName,
            awayTeam.DivisionPoolId AS AwayDivisionPoolId,
            awayTeam.DivisionPoolName AS AwayDivisionPoolName,
            awayTeam.DivisionPoolLabel AS AwayDivisionPoolLabel,
            awayTeam.DivisionBracketId AS AwayDivisionBracketId,
            awayTeam.DivisionBracketName AS AwayDivisionBracketName,
            awayTeam.Number AS AwayNumber,
            awayTeam.Seed AS AwaySeed,
            awayTeam.WinnerBracketGameId AS AwayTeamWinnerBracketGameId,
            awayTeam.LoserBracketGameId AS AwayTeamLoserBracketGameId,
            awayTeam.WinnerBracketGameNumber AS AwayTeamWinnerBracketGameNumber,
            awayTeam.LoserBracketGameNumber AS AwayTeamLoserBracketGameNumber,
            awayTeam.Exhibition AS AwayTeamExhibition,
            homeTeam.Score AS HomeTeamScore,
            homeTeam.Forfeited AS HomeTeamForfeited,
            homeTeam.DivisionTeamId AS HomeDivisionTeamId,
            homeTeam.ActivatedDate AS HomeTeamActivationDate,
            homeTeam.TeamName AS HomeTeamName,
            homeTeam.DivisionPoolId AS HomeDivisionPoolId,
            homeTeam.DivisionPoolName AS HomeDivisionPoolName,
            homeTeam.DivisionPoolLabel AS HomeDivisionPoolLabel,
            homeTeam.DivisionBracketId AS HomeDivisionBracketId,
            homeTeam.DivisionBracketName AS HomeDivisionBracketName,
            homeTeam.Exhibition AS HomeTeamExhibition,
            homeTeam.Number AS HomeNumber,
            homeTeam.Seed AS HomeSeed,
            homeTeam.WinnerBracketGameId AS HomeTeamWinnerBracketGameId,
            homeTeam.LoserBracketGameId AS HomeTeamLoserBracketGameId,
            homeTeam.WinnerBracketGameNumber AS HomeTeamWinnerBracketGameNumber,
            homeTeam.LoserBracketGameNumber AS HomeTeamLoserBracketGameNumber,
            divisionBracket.Id AS DivisionBracketId,
            divisionBracket.Name AS DivisionBracketName,
            COALESCE(poolDivision.Id, bracketDivision.Id) AS DivisionId,
            COALESCE(poolDivision.Name, bracketDivision.Name) AS DivisionName,
            COALESCE(poolDivision.Gender, bracketDivision.Gender) AS DivisionGender,
            COALESCE(poolEvent.Id, bracketEvent.Id) AS EventId,
            COALESCE(poolEventParent.Name, bracketEventParent.Name) AS EventName,
            game.DateModified,
            COALESCE(poolEvent.TimeZone, bracketEvent.TimeZone) AS TimeZone,
            game.DeviceCustomerId
        FROM 
            GrassrootsHoops.Game game LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.GymCourt gymCourt ON gymCourt.Id = game.GymCourtId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.Gym gym ON gym.Id = gymCourt.GymId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.[Address] addr ON addr.Id = gym.AddressId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.[State] stat ON stat.Id = addr.StateRegionId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.Court court ON court.Id = gymCourt.CourtId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    divisionGameTeamResult.Id,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.GameId,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.Score,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.Forfeited,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam,

                    divisionTeamPool.Id AS DivisionTeamPoolId,

                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionTeam.Id, divisionTeamBracket.Id), divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id) AS DivisionTeamId,
                    COALESCE(COALESCE(team.Name, teamBracket.Name), teamPoolTeamBracket.Name) AS TeamName,
                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionTeam.ActivatedDate, divisionTeamBracket.ActivatedDate), divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.ActivatedDate) AS ActivatedDate,

                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionPool.Id, divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id), divisionPoolBracket.Id)  AS DivisionPoolId,
                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionPool.Name, divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Name), divisionPoolBracket.Name) AS DivisionPoolName,
                    divisionPoolSettings.Label AS DivisionPoolLabel,

                    divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Id AS DivisionBracketId,
                    divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Name AS DivisionBracketName,

                    CAST(COALESCE(divisionTeamPoolGame.Exhibition, 0) AS BIT) AS Exhibition,
                    divisionTeamPool.Number AS Number,
                    divisionBracketParticipantPool.DivisionPoolSeed AS Seed,

                    divisionBracketParticipantPart.Number AS BracketGameNumber,
                    divisionBracketParticipantPart.[Round] AS BracketRound,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionWinnerBracketGameId AS WinnerBracketGameId,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionLoserBracketGameId AS LoserBracketGameId,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionWinnerBracketGameNumber AS WinnerBracketGameNumber,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionLoserBracketGameNumber AS LoserBracketGameNumber
                FROM
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionGameTeamResult divisionGameTeamResult LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPoolGame divisionTeamPoolGame ON divisionTeamPoolGame.Id = divisionGameTeamResult.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoopS.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPool ON divisionTeamPool.Id = divisionTeamPoolGame.DivisionTeamPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPool ON divisionPool.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPoolSettings divisionPoolSettings ON divisionPool.Id = divisionPoolSettings.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeam ON divisionTeam.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.Team team ON team.Id = divisionTeam.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipant divisionBracketParticipant ON divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionGameTeamResultId = divisionGameTeamResult.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPart divisionBracketParticipantPart ON divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionBracketParticipantPartId LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeam divisionBracketParticipantTeam ON divisionBracketParticipantTeam.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamBracket ON divisionTeamBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantTeam.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.Team teamBracket ON teamBracket.Id = divisionTeamBracket.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracket ON divisionBracketParticipantBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket ON divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantBracket.DivisionBracketId LEFT OUTER JOIN       

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPool divisionBracketParticipantPool ON divisionBracketParticipantPool.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPoolBracket ON divisionPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantPool.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeamPool divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool ON divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPoolBracket ON divisionTeamPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool.DivisionTeamPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket ON divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket ON divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.Team teamPoolTeamBracket ON teamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id
                WHERE divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam = 1
            ) homeTeam ON homeTeam.GameId = game.Id INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    divisionGameTeamResult.Id,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.GameId,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.Score,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.Forfeited,
                    divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam,

                    divisionTeamPool.Id AS DivisionTeamPoolId,

                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionTeam.Id, divisionTeamBracket.Id), divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id) AS DivisionTeamId,
                    COALESCE(COALESCE(team.Name, teamBracket.Name), teamPoolTeamBracket.Name) AS TeamName,
                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionTeam.ActivatedDate, divisionTeamBracket.ActivatedDate), divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.ActivatedDate) AS ActivatedDate,

                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionPool.Id, divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id), divisionPoolBracket.Id)  AS DivisionPoolId,
                    COALESCE(COALESCE(divisionPool.Name, divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Name), divisionPoolBracket.Name) AS DivisionPoolName,
                    divisionPoolSettings.Label AS DivisionPoolLabel,

                    divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Id AS DivisionBracketId,
                    divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Name AS DivisionBracketName,

                    CAST(COALESCE(divisionTeamPoolGame.Exhibition, 0) AS BIT) AS Exhibition,
                    divisionTeamPool.Number AS Number,
                    divisionBracketParticipantPool.DivisionPoolSeed AS Seed,

                    divisionBracketParticipantPart.Number AS BracketGameNumber,
                    divisionBracketParticipantPart.[Round] AS BracketRound,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionWinnerBracketGameId AS WinnerBracketGameId,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionLoserBracketGameId AS LoserBracketGameId,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionWinnerBracketGameNumber AS WinnerBracketGameNumber,
                    divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionLoserBracketGameNumber AS LoserBracketGameNumber
                FROM
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionGameTeamResult divisionGameTeamResult LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPoolGame divisionTeamPoolGame ON divisionTeamPoolGame.Id = divisionGameTeamResult.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoopS.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPool ON divisionTeamPool.Id = divisionTeamPoolGame.DivisionTeamPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPool ON divisionPool.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPoolSettings divisionPoolSettings ON divisionPool.Id = divisionPoolSettings.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeam ON divisionTeam.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.Team team ON team.Id = divisionTeam.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipant divisionBracketParticipant ON divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionGameTeamResultId = divisionGameTeamResult.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPart divisionBracketParticipantPart ON divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionBracketParticipantPartId LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeam divisionBracketParticipantTeam ON divisionBracketParticipantTeam.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamBracket ON divisionTeamBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantTeam.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.Team teamBracket ON teamBracket.Id = divisionTeamBracket.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracket ON divisionBracketParticipantBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket ON divisionBracketParticipantBracketBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantBracket.DivisionBracketId LEFT OUTER JOIN       

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPool divisionBracketParticipantPool ON divisionBracketParticipantPool.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPoolBracket ON divisionPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantPool.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantTeamPool divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool ON divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPoolBracket ON divisionTeamPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool.DivisionTeamPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket ON divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeam divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket ON divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    GrassrootsHoops.Team teamPoolTeamBracket ON teamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id
                WHERE divisionGameTeamResult.HomeTeam = 0
            ) awayTeam ON awayTeam.GameId = game.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN

            GrassrootsHoops.DivisionTeamPoolGame divisionTeamPoolGame ON divisionTeamPoolGame.Id = awayTeam.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoopS.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPool ON divisionTeamPool.Id = divisionTeamPoolGame.DivisionTeamPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.DivisionPool divisionPool ON divisionPool.Id = divisionTeamPool.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.Division poolDivision ON poolDivision.Id = divisionPool.DivisionId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.[Event] poolEvent ON poolEvent.Id = poolDivision.EventId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.EventGym eventGymPool ON eventGymPool.GymId = gymCourt.GymId AND eventGymPool.EventId = poolEvent.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.[EventParent] poolEventParent ON poolEventParent.Id = poolEvent.EventParentId LEFT OUTER JOIN

            GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipant divisionBracketParticipant ON divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionGameTeamResultId = awayTeam.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketParticipantPart divisionBracketParticipantPart ON divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionBracketParticipantPartId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracketPart divisionBracketPart ON divisionBracketPart.Id = divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.DivisionBracket divisionBracket ON divisionBracket.Id = divisionBracketPart.DivisionBracketId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.Division bracketDivision ON bracketDivision.Id = divisionBracket.DivisionId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.[Event] bracketEvent ON bracketEvent.Id = bracketDivision.EventId LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.EventGym eventGymBracket ON eventGymBracket.GymId = gymCourt.GymId AND eventGymBracket.EventId = bracketEvent.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GrassrootsHoops.[EventParent] bracketEventParent ON bracketEventParent.Id = bracketEvent.EventParentId 

            WHERE 
                (poolEvent.Visible = 1 OR bracketEvent.Visible = 1) AND
                (poolDivision.Visible = 1 OR bracketDivision.Visible = 1) AND
                (@EventId IS NULL OR (poolEvent.Id = @EventId OR bracketEvent.Id = @EventId)) AND
                (@GymCourtId IS NULL OR (game.GymCourtId = @GymCourtId)) AND
                (@DivisionId IS NULL OR (poolDivision.Id = @DivisionId OR bracketDivision.Id = @DivisionId)) AND
                (@DivisionTeamId IS NULL OR (awayTeam.DivisionTeamId = @DivisionTeamId OR homeTeam.DivisionTeamId = @DivisionTeamId)) AND
                (@Date IS NULL OR (DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, game.[Date]), 0) = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, @Date), 0))) AND
                (@SearchToken IS NULL OR awayTeam.TeamName LIKE ('%' + @SearchToken + '%') OR homeTeam.TeamName LIKE ('%' + @SearchToken + '%')) AND
                (@GameType IS NULL OR (CASE 
                    WHEN DivisionTeamPoolGame.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                    WHEN divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                    ELSE NULL 
                 END
                ) = @GameType) AND
                (@MemberId IS NULL OR EXISTS(
                                        SELECT me.EventId 
                                        FROM GrassrootsHoops.MemberEvent me 
                                        WHERE me.EventId = poolEvent.Id OR me.EventId = bracketEvent.Id AND me.MemberId = @MemberId))
    )

    SELECT 
            [Row] + RowReverse - 1 AS Total, 
            [Row],
            [RowReverse],
            Id, 
            Number,
            GameType,
            [Date], 
            [Time],
            TwitterId,
            FacebookId,
            GymId,
            GymCourtId,
            GymName,
            GymAbbr,
            GymOrder,
            CourtOrder,
            CourtName,
            CourtAbbr,
            StreetAddress,
            ExtendedAddress,
            City,
            StateRegion,
            PostalCode,
            Longitude,
            Latitude,
            AwayTeamScore,
            AwayTeamForfeited,
            AwayDivisionTeamId,
            AwayTeamActivationDate,
            AwayTeamName,
            AwayDivisionPoolId,
            AwayDivisionPoolName,
            AwayDivisionPoolLabel,
            AwayDivisionBracketId,
            AwayDivisionBracketName,
            AwayNumber,
            AwaySeed,
            AwayTeamWinnerBracketGameId,
            AwayTeamLoserBracketGameId,
            AwayTeamWinnerBracketGameNumber,
            AwayTeamLoserBracketGameNumber,
            AwayTeamExhibition,
            HomeTeamScore,
            HomeTeamForfeited,
            HomeDivisionTeamId,
            HomeTeamActivationDate,
            HomeTeamName,
            HomeDivisionPoolId,
            HomeDivisionPoolName,
            HomeDivisionPoolLabel,
            HomeDivisionBracketId,
            HomeDivisionBracketName,
            HomeNumber,
            HomeSeed,
            HomeTeamWinnerBracketGameId,
            HomeTeamLoserBracketGameId,
            HomeTeamWinnerBracketGameNumber,
            HomeTeamLoserBracketGameNumber,
            HomeTeamExhibition,
            [Round],
            DivisionBracketId,
            DivisionBracketName,
            DivisionId,
            DivisionName,
            DivisionGender,
            EventId,
            EventName,
            DateModified, 
            TimeZone,
            DeviceCustomerId
    FROM PagedResults
    WHERE [Row] BETWEEN (((@Page - 1) * @PageSize) + 1) AND (@Page * @PageSize)
    ORDER BY [Row], [RowReverse] DESC
    OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Page = '1'))
END
```

Comment: _Please just show your query, it's painfull to imagine it._
For you information, none of **stored procedure** and `left outer join` are performance killer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, doing less work is faster than doing more work.  Removing tables from your query will make the query quicker.  It will not be returning columns for the other game type filled with `NULL`s either, which will also help.  How much quicker will depend on just how big "a lot" is.  Five statements & 10 rows, twice a day - you ain't gonna notice.  One thousand statements, one hundred million rows, fifty times a second?  Oh yeah!

Depending on how complicated the rest of the query is splitting may give the optimiser a better chance of finding the best plan, too.  If its a three-way query becoming two-way this won't be significant.

Most important is having proper indexes on the primary and foreign key columns in all three tables, and keeping statistics up-to-date.

Is the game -> pool relationship 1-to-1 or 1-to-many?  SQL Server (at least) can suffer from parameter sniffing (Google it), which may throw off your performance for subsequent executions after a recompile.

HTH.

Comment: 1:1, I tried parameter sniffing fix using parameters and it made it 3 times slower.